# When i use ExecuteScalar command returns an empty object

Tags: c#, sql-server, tostring, visual-studio-2008-sp1, executescalar

What is wrong with my code?

When I use this block of code in Visual Studio 2008 C# the `curid` output value is `""`, where I have 2 values in my database so it should return 2...

Also when I run a query

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')
```

directly in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns the correct value.

```
string curid = "";

cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select IDENT_CURRENT('@tblname')";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblname", tableName);

cmd.Connection = con;
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
curid = obj.ToString();
```

Comment: As far as I know, you *cannot* parametrize the table name here - you'd have to use simple string concatenation to build that query you successfully execute in SSMS and then run that against SQL Server.

Comment: additionally, one would *not* place a parameter within single-quotes.

Comment: sorry i didnt know that,, i was used to parameterized query anyways i've already solved this

Comment: I was wrong in my first comment - you *can* indeed use a parameter here - as long as you don't put it into single quotes (and preferably don't use the `.AddWithValue` method - [see here for more details *why* to avoid that](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) ).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit your CommandText to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select IDENT_CURRENT(' " + tableName + "')";
```

Comment: @Poiedon, better yet, stick you your parameterized query and omit the quotes.